# Using lambda function to find element from another list or array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lambda

**Edited the Question for Clarification**

```
import numpy as np
tt = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
st = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
def abc():
    return lambda x: st[np.where(tt==x)] if (50 < x <100) else 0
print(abc()(tt))
```

Expectation is that for a given, long **periodic** time-series **tt** with a period of **100**, the function abc() should output the values in **st** for the interval 50-100, 150-200, 250-300, and spit out 0 elsewhere. Something like..

```
[0....0..st.....st.0.....0.st....st.0....0.st.....st]
```

---

**Previously asked....**

I inherited a long code to which I need to do some modification. The basic format is a number of functions, each returning a lambda function

```
def func1():
  return lambda x: #some math with x, like x**2

def func2():
  return lambda x: #some math with x, like np.sin(x)
```

and so on..

These functions are supplied with a time-series, t, a numpy 1D array from which the required math function is generated. It works properly.

For instance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0, 100, 1)

def fun1():
  return lambda x: x**2

print(fun1()(t)) 
plt.plot(t, fun1()(t))
plt.savefig('Graph.png')
```

Now I wish to import/read data from an external file as a [time, value] pair and use that to generate the new math function, instead of doing math in the function itself as before.

After reading from a file, I have say,

```
time = [0, 0.1, 0.2, ..... 1000.0]
value = [v1, v2, ...........vn]
```

I want to do

```
def new_func():
   return lambda x: "*Looking for an answer*"
```

So that if I call **new_func**()(t), I get the **value** as the output

I have tried np.where, and tried defining subfuctions. But nothing has worked so far. Because I have to pass this function to another code, I can't change the basic format. Please advise.

Comment: The word "generated" has a very strange usage here. Give a concrete example with an actual file containing actual numbers and an actual function you "generated".

Comment: Just edited with a simple example that works.

Answer (score 3):

`lambda` *is* a function by itself. Putting it into a `def` formal function as the sole output make no sense.

If you want to multiply by 2 for an entire list, `lambda` will not be enough, you'll also need an iterator. The following:

```
func = lambda x: x*2
```

Simply means this is an lambda function that will return input*2, it is equivalent to:

```
def func(x): return x*2
```

If you want to make it apply to an entire list, you'll need to do:

```
list(map(lambda x: x*2, mylist))
```

`map` will map the function to each element of the list, but that will also work for a named function.

In order to make your purpose, assuming both `value` and `time` are `list` of same length.

```
lambda t: value[time.index(t)]
```

is the function you need. Call it like this:

```
(lambda t: value[time.index(t)])(t)
# OR:
func = lambda t: value[time.index(t)] # assign it name and then
func(t)
```

Comment: I intend to use the value as read from the file, not use any mathematics in the lambda function.

Comment: You need to give a clearer picture of what you want to do. I cannot figure out what you want to use it for from what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to be clear. I need the lambda function to take in the time-series and give the appropriate values as an output, from the time-value pair previously read from a file.

Comment: `lambda t: value[time.index(t)]` will do what you need. but you cannot return a `lambda` as it is a function by itself.

Comment: value is giving unresolved reference. Isn't it for dictionaries? Please correct me.

Comment: Isn’t it what you named your list of values?

Comment: The data (time-value pairs) I have are read from a text file. Do you think putting them in a dictionary format would help solve this issue? I can try that.

Comment: I guess I confused my usage of value with the method value. But then my time is a numpy array, and has no attribute index

Comment: Translate that to `list` by `time = list(time)`, alternatively, use `value[np.where(time==t)[0][0]]` I think translating to `list` is less confusing

Comment: With list, it says truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use any() or all(). With np.where, which I had tried earlier, it runs but doesn't give correct values. Picks one value from the array and uses that for all times.

Comment: I cannot replicate, are you sure you're using `lambda t: your_value[your_time.index(t)]` in this format?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am using. I tried with values still being numpy arrays, and also converted them into list as well, like the time series.

Comment: Are you sure you are not duplicating the name of lambda input with the list name of either? There’s the same mistake if I do that.

Comment: No, I double checked. I made another quick example and figured that if at the end I call new_func() with single values, they match and give corresponding correct y-values. But using the time list, new_func()(time) doesn't work.

Comment: You need to wrap your lambda function (lambda: ..)() to call it like a function

Comment: I am calling it as you said. Please have a look at the edited version of the question in the title post. The code snippet posted above gives the error I mentioned earlier.